# Using function composition to turn a function into point free one

Tags: functional-programming, programming-paradigms

In [Tacit Programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tacit_programming) page on wikipedia, it is stated that the point free version of

`p x y z = f (g x y) z` is
`p = ((.) f) . g`

and that the point free version of

`mf criteria operator list = filter criteria (map operator list)` is
`mf = (. map) . (.) . filter`.

I can not figure out how can we get from one side to the other, in either way. Would you please show me a step by step explanation of why those equivalences hold?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Going from the point-free version to the lambda version is mechanical. Remember that composition is defined by `(f . g) = (.) f g = \x. f (g x)`, so `(f . g) x = f (g x)`. Remember also that `(f . g)` is syntactic sugar for `(.) f g` and `f x y` is shorthand for `(f x) y`. It's easier to follow what's going on if you apply one argument at a time.

```
p = ((.) f) . g
p x = (((.) f) . g) x = ((.) f) (g x) = (.) f (g x)
p x y = (p x) y = ((.) f (g x)) y = (.) f (g x) y = (f . g x) y = f (g x y)
p x y z = (p x y) z = (f (g x y)) z = f (g x y) z
```

To go in the other direction, arrange the function calls so that there is a single occurrence of the function's parameter in the function body, and arrange it to be at the end of the call. In addition to `.` for composition, this may require the use of auxiliary functions such as `flip` to change the order of arguments.

```
p x y z = f (g x y) z
p x y = f (g x y)
p x = \y. f (g x y) = \y. f ((g x) y) = \y. (f . g x) y = (f . g x) = ((.) f) (g x)
p = \x. ((.) f) (g x) = \x. ((.) f . g) x = ((.) f . g)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your clear answer. I also found the answer to the second equality (filter criteria (map operator list)) that I have posted as a separate answer. Can you please add it to yours just to make yours complete?

Comment: Can you please give me an example of the case where you would arrange the function call so that there is a single occurrence of the function's parameter?

Answer (score 0):

I found the following at [[Haskell-cafe] Exercise in point free-style](https://mail.haskell.org/pipermail/haskell-cafe/2006-September/017758.html) which states that:

```
func2 f g l = filter f (map g l)
func2 f g = (filter f) . (map g)    -- definition of (.)
func2 f g = ((.) (filter f)) (map g)    -- desugaring
func2 f = ((.) (filter f)) . map    -- definition of (.)
func2 f = flip (.) map ((.) (filter f)) -- desugaring, def. of flip
func2 = flip (.) map . (.) . filter     -- def. of (.), twice
func2 = (. map) . (.) . filter      -- add back some sugar
```