# What is the point-free version of f(x,y)?

Tags: functional-programming, programming-paradigms

What is the point-free version of

```
f(x, y)
```

? Is it just f or some kind of function composition, since when curried there is an implicit function which is made out of applying f to x?

Comment: As far as I know, function definitions do not identify the arguments on which they operate. Instead the definitions merely compose other functions, among which are combinators that manipulate the arguments. For example, if your code was written in python, it would be something like `f(*args)`

Comment: @aminrd Thanks for your reply. Would you please elaborate a bit further. The reason for this question is the [this question](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/115109/using-function-composition-to-turn-a-function-into-point-free-one)  which states that point free version of `p x y z = f (g x y) z` is `p = ((.) f) . g`

Comment: There are tools that will mechanically do these conversions for Haskell code. Assuming you mean this to be a function of `x` and `y` (and not of `f`...), then you can stick `\x y -> f(x,y)` into http://pointfree.io/ and get an answer.

Comment: @Derek It gives: `(f .) . (,)` . What is `(,)` supposed to mean? Sorry I'm not that familiar with Haskell!

Comment: @alpal `(,)` is constructor of pair. It's of type `(,) :: a -> b -> (a, b)`

Comment: I defined f as `f :: Num a => a -> a -> a`. Now I get `Num a1 => a2 -> a1 -> (a2, a1 -> a1)` as the type of `(. f) . (,)`. Is that correct? and should `((. f) . (,)) 2 3` give me a number as the result?

Comment: No... I have a guess where you might get confused. Remember that if you write `f (x,y)`, you are applying single argument which is pair `(x,y)` to `f`. On the other hand, `f x y` means you are applying 2 arguments to `f`.